# Express nodejs session cookies: req.cookies['connect.sid'] is not generated and req.sessionID is different after each refresh

Tags: node.js, session, express, cookies, sessionid

I use express 4.13.3 and express-session 1.11.3. Here my configuration session:

```
app.use( session({/*store: new redis_store,*/name: 'connect.sid', secret: 'azerty is qwerty', resave: false, saveUninitialized: false, cookie:{httpOnly: false, secure: false, maxAge: null}}) );
```

Here I print `req.cookies['connect.sid']` and `req.sessionID` :

```
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.sessionID);
  console.log(req.cookies['connect.sid']);

  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

On each refresh `req.sessionID` is **different** and `req.cookies['connect.sid']` is **undefined**. Some months ago, as `req.sessionID` was changing at refresh, I decided to use `req.cookies['connect.sid']` and it was working like a charm. Today I checked my code and I notice that `connect.sid` doesn't exist anymore in the cookie.

So what is the problem? How I can use the session id of the cookie?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`req.session.id` is the same as `req.sessionID` and `req.session.cookie` is the session config object.

After some tests I concluded that, if you want to access `req.cookies['connect.sid']`, you need to **use** manually the session. For example, you can write `req.session.i = 1` or whatever. Then the id `connect.sid` will be visible in your navigator (using Chrome Dev Tools for instance). Moreover, if you want that `req.sessionID` stays the same, you must not forget to call `res.sendStatus(200)` or another response at the end of the function.

But one problem persists. Look at this code:

```
app.post("/upload-files", upload.array('files'), function (req, res, next) { 
    if(!req.session.i) req.session.i = 0;
    ++req.session.i;
    console.log("i: " + req.session.i);
}
```

Here I send a `post` request with an array of files using `multer`. As `multer` doesn't work with names of the form "files[]" (see [multer-not-accepting-files-in-array-format-gives-unexpected-filed-error-used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35164282/multer-not-accepting-files-in-array-format-gives-unexpected-filed-error-used)), I am obliged to send the files one by one. Here the problem occurs: the variable `i` will not persist and will stay equal to 1.

I think that they are some bugs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to access these objects like so:

```
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  console.log(req.session.id);
  console.log(req.session.cookie);

  res.sendStatus(200);
});
```

Also the [express-session docs](https://github.com/expressjs/session) say that `connect.sid` is the default name for session cookies, so you don't need to specify it like you are doing.